# [Stephen Willard, General Topology Exc. 28B]: Any linearly orderered set with the following properties is order isomorphic to the dyadic rationals

Tags: general-topology

I have a question concerning problem 28B in Stephen Willard's General Topology (Section Connectedness - Continua). 
It states:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be ordered spaces. A map $f$ of $X$ onto $Y$ is an order isomorphism if and only if it is one-one and $x<y \Leftrightarrow f(x)<f(y)$.

1. Every order isomorphism is a homeomorphism relative to the order topologies on $X$ and $Y$.
2. Let $P$ denote the set of dyadic rationals in $(0,1)$. Then

   - $P$ has no largest or smallest element
   - if $p,q \in P$ with $p < q$, then for some $r \in P$, $p < r <q$.
3. Every countable linearly ordered (nonempty) set $D$ with the properties in (2) is order isomorphic to $P$.

How do i proof (1) and (3)?

And as a follow-up question: Why does a countable dense subset with these two properties always exist in a continuum with exactly two non-cutpoints?

(This is in reference to theorem 28.13. in the same book, where this problem is used in the proof.)

Comment: I think you also need to assume $D$ is nonempty and has no smallest element.  (Unless the definition of "ordered space" already implies nonempty somehow.)

Comment: Hint for 1: to prove an order isomorphism $f$ is continuous, prove that for each subbasic open subset $(b, \infty)$ of $Y$, $f^{-1}( (b, \infty) ) = (f^{-1}(b), \infty)$, and similarly for subbasic open subsets $(-\infty, b)$,  And similarly, to prove $f$ is open, prove that $f( (a, \infty) ) = (f(a), \infty)$ and similarly for $f( (-\infty, a) )$.

Comment: 3. can be proved by [Cantor's back and forth argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-and-forth_method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the first paragraph of [this proof](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/25.pdf) using Cantor's classical back and forth argument for 3.

nr 1. is clear, as the standard subbase elements for the order topology, i.e. sets of the form $(a, \rightarrow)$ and $(\leftarrow, b)$ are preserved by order preserving bijections. Inverse images of those (in both directions) are of the same form, so open as well.